# How to get the element width and height immediately when it resizing in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, resize

How to get the element width and height immediately when it resizing in Vue.js?
Here is my code pen illustration 
please help me to change it till work,thanks!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/weretyc/pen/zEvVZj)

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    boxs: [{
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      },
      {
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      }
    ]
  }

});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.resize {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  background-color: #C3E2CE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="box,key in boxs" class="resize">
    {{ box.width }} x {{ box.height }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

To get immediate feedback that responds to the actual resize action, you might want to try using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).  You can attach it to a `ref` point of your component and listen for mutations there.

You can attach the `MutationObserver` in the `mounted` function.  Be sure to also do any cleanup that you need in the `destroyed` function.

```js
const Resizable = {
  template: "<div ref='main' @resize='onResize' class='resize'>{{dims.width}} | {{dims.height}}</div>",
  data() {
    return {
      dims: {
        width: null,
        height: null
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const {
      width,
      height
    } = this.$refs.main.getBoundingClientRect();

    this.dims.width = width;
    this.dims.height = height;

    const mutationHandler = mutationList => {
      for (let mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
          const {
            width,
            height
          } = mutation.target.getBoundingClientRect();

          this.dims.width = width;
          this.dims.height = height;
        }
      }
    };
    const mo = new MutationObserver(mutationHandler);

    mo.observe(this.$refs.main, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });

  },
  methods: {
    onResize() {
      console.log("Resized");
    }
  }
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    "resizable": Resizable
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "fizz"
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #414141;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <resizable v-for="item in items" :key="item" class="resize"></resizable>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy way would be plain JS `eventListener` to change a local variable

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);

data() {
  return {
    windowWidth:0
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.$nextTick(function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
    this.getWindowWidth()
  })
},
methods: {
getWindowWidth() {
  this.windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
}
}
```

and don't forget to remove the `eventListener` on component destroy

```
beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, but I'm still learning Vue as well. I'd suggest you do more modular approach and extract the boxes, then just loop how many you want. Please note that this is not best-practice, as the box w/h should probably be coming from props and data being loaded from the root element.

```js
const box = Vue.component("box", {
  template: '<div class="resize">{{ boxWidth }} x {{ boxHeight}}</div>',
  data() {
    return {
      boxWidth: 100,
      boxHeight: 100,
    };
  },
  mounted: function() { 
    this.$el.addEventListener("mouseup", this.move);
  },
  methods: {
    move(e) {
      if (e.target == this.$el) {
        this.boxWidth = parseInt(this.$el.style.width);
        this.boxHeight = parseInt(this.$el.style.height);
      }
    }
  }
});

let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { box: box },
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.resize {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  background-color: #C3E2CE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="b in [0,1]">
      <box></box>
    </div>
</div>
```