# How to detect the real-time height change of div1 in Vue3 and get the height of div1 minus 12px for div2?

Tags: css, vuejs3

I have a problem that I can't solve.
How can I detect the real-time height change of div1 in Vue3 and obtain the height of div1 minus 12px for div2?

If div1 contains multiple lines of text and its height expands from 100px to 150px, how can I obtain the value of 150px - 12px = 138px for div2 and assign a height of 138px to div2?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cZqQ.png)

I apologize for any confusion caused. English is not my primary language. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Best regards.

I can capture the initial height, but I cannot capture it in real-time when it changes height.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the element width and height immediately when it resizing in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275778/how-to-get-the-element-width-and-height-immediately-when-it-resizing-in-vue-js)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use CSS?

Comment: Is div1 content track-able by Vue? If so, you can do with watchers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the picture!!

Use `MutationObserver`:

```js
<script setup>
import {
    ref,
    watch,
  onBeforeUnmount
} from 'vue'

const heightDiv1 = ref(0)
const mutationHandler = mutationList => {
    for (let mutation of mutationList) {
        if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
            const {
                height
            } = mutation.target.getBoundingClientRect();

            heightDiv1.value = height
        }
    }
};
const mo = new MutationObserver(mutationHandler);
onBeforeUnmount(() => mo.disconnect())

const div1Ref = ref()
watch(div1Ref, (div1Ref) => {
    if (!div1Ref) return
    heightDiv1.value = div1Ref.getBoundingClientRect().height

    mo.observe(div1Ref, {
        attributes: true,
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="div1Ref" class="div1">
    div 1
    <textarea />
  </div>
  Height div 1: {{heightDiv1}}
  <div :style="{ height: heightDiv1 - 12 + 'px'}" class="div2">
    div 2
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .div1 {
    background: red
  }
  .div2 {
    background: blue
  }
</style>
```

Preview: https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   import { ref } from 'vue'

   const input = ref(null);
   const second = ref(null);

   var height = 0; // to store first div height
   var height2 = 0; // to store second div height
   watchEffect(() => {
       const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
          height = (input.current || {}).clientHeight || 0;
          if (height > 0) height2 = height - 12;
       });
   });

</script>

<template>
  <div1 ref = "input" />
  <div2 ref = "second" />
</template>
```

Here is a workaround for your problem. The ResizeObserver calculates the height when the text inside the div changes. To Listen to this event watchEffect is being used to keep track of it. I hope this will work for you. I don't work on vue but gave it a try similar to react. So, apologize if there is any mistake.

Comment: a bad answer and doesn't seem to work. why are you wrapping them in `watchEffect`? furthermore `Ref`s don't have `prototype` `current`